# Star Wars Rogue One is set in what period? Do the events take place before "The Force Awakens"?

Tags: star-wars, chronology, rogue-one

I have watched only one Star Wars movie, which is *The Force Awakens*.

I want to watch Rogue One but having no idea about the previous SIX movies, I have no idea what to expect from the movie.

Do the events take place after *The Force Awakens* or before it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This movie takes place right before the events of *Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope*.

> In Rogue One, they steal the plans of Death Star and give it to Princess Leia. That is where this movie ends and this event leads to the beginning of A New Hope.

*The Force Awakens* takes place after the events of *Episode VI: Return of the Jedi* which is the successor of *Episode V: Empire Strikes Back*. Episode V is the successor of *A New Hope*.

For more details, you can see [this related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65237/27264).

Comment: I confused *Force Awakens* with *[Force Unleashed\*](https://goo.gl/Rfl7HD)* (which would have been a more interesting question, since it takes place between Episode III and IV) and this answer confused the hell out of me before realizing.